# How to get logged in user details in viewset - django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class loksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):        
    k='3'
    print(type(k))
    queryset = loks.objects.all().filter(mp=k)
    serializer_class = loksSerializer
```

In the above code i need to get the k value from first name of logged in user. How can i get that.

Comment: request.user not working?

Comment: yes request.user not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need the logged in user then you'd need to use `get_queryset` instead of setting the `queryset` like

```py
class loksViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):        
    serializer_class = loksSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        print(self.request.user) # this would print the user
        return loks.objects.all() # or you can filter it how you want, depending on your needs
```

if you need the first name of the user you can access it from

```
self.request.user.first_name
```

take a look at this
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: thank u very much, ur answer is worked, previously i used get instead of get_queryset. Hence not worked But i can't vote showing need more reputation to vote

Comment: @mohan no need to vote, you can select the answer as the correct answer by clicking the tick mark under the vote buttons and turn it green